# Troubleshoot MS DTC error

Tags: sql-server, errors, extended-events, msdtc

I've been getting these two errors on SQL Server log:

**Error 1:**

> DESCRIPTION:    Import of Microsoft Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator (MS DTC) transaction failed:
>   0x8004d00e(XACT_E_NOTRANSACTION).

**Error 2:**

> DESCRIPTION:    Enlist operation failed:
>   0x8004d00e(XACT_E_NOTRANSACTION). SQL Server could not register with
>   Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) as a resource
>   manager for this transaction. The transaction may have been stopped by
>   the client or the resource manager.

It happens at random times and I don't know how to track and associate it with any job or application request. No change has been made to the server that I'm awere of.

**Here's what I have done so far:**

- Verified that Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is running on Windows;
- Event Viewer didn't show any error I could relate to the problem;
- Firewall is off while I'm troubleshooting;
- Followed the instructions to [Configure DTC
  Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731495(v=ws.11)?redirectedfrom=MSDN);
- Have seen similar threads like
  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414250/msdtc-on-server-server-is-unavailable)
  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883309/the-msdtc-transaction-manager-was-unable-to-push-the-transaction-to-the-destinat);
- Tried to [uninstall and
  install](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/troubleshooting-problems-with-msdtc?redirectedfrom=MSDN#consider-reinstalling-the-distributed-transaction-coordinator-service-if-other-troubleshooting-steps-are-not-successful) MSDTC;
- Tested the DTC with `dtctester.exe` and here's the output:
  [image: output of dtctester]

**EDIT 1:**

- Ran test using **DTCping** and it showed an error:
  [image: dtcping result]
  To fix DTCping error I [Set the appropriate values for the EnableAuthEpResolution and RestrictRemoteClients options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/troubleshooting-problems-with-msdtc?redirectedfrom=MSDN#set-the-appropriate-values-for-the-enableauthepresolution-and-restrictremoteclients-options) on the client side;
- Tested the DTC with `dtctester.exe` again and now it worked fine;

**EDIT 2:**

- Configured **Extended Events**. It captured the error and brought
  information about the user, database and server involved on the
  error, but it wasn't enough to find out the culprit. Here's the code
  used to create the XE session:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [MSDTC_TROUBLESHOOT] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.errorlog_written(
    ACTION(package0.callstack,sqlos.task_time,sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.client_hostname,sqlserver.client_pid,sqlserver.database_name,sqlserver.sql_text,sqlserver.username)
    WHERE ([sqlserver].[client_hostname]=N'MyAppServer' AND [sqlserver].[database_name]=N'MyDatabase'))
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

Even though MSDTC passed the tests I'm still getting the two errors on SQL Server log. Is there anything else I can do find out what is causing them?

Comment: Are you testing a single host only, or between hosts? Also, have you tried DTCPing to verify basic communication for DTC is working? [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918331/how-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues-in-ms-dtc-by-using-the-dtcping)

Comment: @HandyD I'm testing between hosts. I haven't tried `DTCPing`. I thought I read an article which said there was no need to use it when the server being tested had a SQL Server. Probably my mistake after reading so many things. I used `DTCPing` as you suggested and it showed an error that I corrected and the error with the `dtctester.exe` changed. I was able to fix that other error too and now MSDTC seems to be working fine. I'm gonna write the steps in a complete answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HandyD would **Extended Events** be a useful tool in this case? I've never used it. Any advise before I start digging with it?

Comment: Have you enabled the [MSDTC log](https://mariuszgorzoch.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/reading-msdtc-log/) to try and identify the source? Also, try adding error_reported event into your XE session to capture details from the session that fails which might give you more information.